# Python Script: replacing values in CSV's

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

In my python script, I'm trying to read into csv files and if it has a column "PROD_NAME", it finds a value within that column and replaces it with another value. Currently, whenever I run the script, everything is going through the "try" clause and acts like it is working but when I look into the file itself, the values remain unchanged.. Nothing is hitting the "except" clause and the Command prompt prints replace for each file it supposedly changed.. any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
def worker():
    filenames = glob.glob(dest_dir + '\\*.csv')
    for filename in filenames:# this is loop over files***************************
            
        my_file = Path(os.path.join(dest_dir, filename))

        try:
        
            with open(filename) as f:
            # read data
                df1 = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=1, encoding='ISO-8859-1') # read column header only - to get the list of columns
                dtypes = {}
                #print(filename, df1)
                for col in df1.columns:# make all columns text, to avoid formatting errors
                    dtypes[col] = 'str'
                df1 = pd.read_csv(filename, dtype=dtypes, skiprows=1, encoding='ISO-8859-1')
                if 'PROD_NAME' in df1.columns: 
                    df1 = df1.replace("NA_NRF", "FA_GUAR")
                    print("Replaced" + filename)
                
        except:
            if 'PROD_NAME' in df1.columns:
                print(filename)
                    
worker()
```

Original DF:

```
!4  PROD_NAME   ENTRY_YEAR
*   NA_NRF  2014
```

The NA_NRF is supposed to change to FA_GUAR

Comment: Provide your original data frame and what is the expected output you need.

Comment: added the original. NA_NRF is supposed to change to FA_GUAR

Comment: Why do you do `open(filename)`? You never use `f` for anything.

Comment: You're never saving the updated dataframe to the file. You need `df1.to_csv(filename)` to update the file.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
with open(filename) as f:
   df_before = pd.read_csv(f, sep=';')
   for i in df_before.columns.values:
       if i == "PROD_NAME":
            df_after = df_before.replace("NA_NRF", "FA_GUAR")
            df_after.to_csv(filename, index=False, sep=';')
       else:
           print("nothing to change")
```

- When I added sep=';' it stopped giving me headaches about quotes...